# Rem values have wrong pixel value in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a problem with how chrome renders rem computed values.

My base font pixel size is 16px;

When my rem value is 3.4375rem, chrome renders its pixel value correctly, as 3.4375 * 16 = 55(px);

The problem starts when I have value 3.25rem, for some reason chrome detects this value as 51.9886360168457px which is complete nonsense as 16 x 3.25 = 52(px).

It only happens in chrome and not any other browser, I tested mozilla and IE.

Comment: Floating point calculations in Chrome are often weird. At first I thought it was just regular floating point errors, but the errors are too large. I suspect Chrome is doing something deliberate to stay on the safe side of floating point errors. Like in every calculation it shaves of a thousandth of a pixel or so, to make sure that e.g. 10 divs set to 10% of a container that is 768px wide don't end up being 769px wide and ruining the lay-out.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it isn't actual now, but I'll find this issue too and hope my answer can be helpful for someone.

The calculations of sizes are decimal because your page is scaled on -+ 10% with Ctrl+MouseWheel.
If you press Ctrl+0 you'll see a normally sized page.